# IE11 not responding due to long running scripts

Tags: internet-explorer-11

My application is working fine in all browsers Chrome , Firefox , (except ie 11).
We have a loader that is common for Ajax calling. It get stucks or hangs at some controllers randomly.

IE 11 is displaying a message on the footer "localhost is not responding due to a long running script" .Also note the application is working fine .Assuming this is some thing specific to IE 11 .

Any idea would be appreciable .

Thanks,
Avi Verma.

Comment: Our clients are using IE, so, use Chrome or Firefox are not welcome.